# Let $f:[0,4] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. Then show that $f'(c)=\frac{1}{6}(f'(1)+2f'(2)+3f'(3))$ for some $c \in (0,4)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, mean-value-theorem

Let $f:[0,4] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Show that there exists a $c \in [0,4]$ s.t $f'(c)=\frac{1}{6}\left(f'(1)+2f'(2)+3f'(3)\right)$.

I don't understand where to start this problem. I only took that $f'(\alpha)=\min\{f'(1),f'(2),f'(3)\}$ and $f'(\beta)=\max\{f'(1),f'(2),f'(3)\}$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: First, state the problem correctly: show that there exists some $c \in ]0,4[$ such that ...

Comment: By Darboux theorem, $f'$ achieves in $[\min(\alpha,\beta),\max(\alpha,\beta)]$ every value of the interval $[\min(f'(\alpha),f'(\beta)),\max(f'(\alpha),f'(\beta))]$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan if there is a solution of this problem then it will be very very helpful for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that

$$
\begin{align}
f'(\alpha)&=\frac{1}{6}\left(
f'(\alpha)+
2f'(\alpha)+
3f'(\alpha)
\right)\\
&\leq\frac{1}{6}\left(
f'(1)+
2f'(2)+
3f'(3)
\right)\\
&\leq\frac{1}{6}\left(
f'(\beta)+
2f'(\beta)+
3f'(\beta)
\right)=f'(\beta)
\end{align}
$$

Hence $\frac{1}{6}\left(
f'(1)+
2f'(2)+
3f'(3)
\right)\in\left[f'(\alpha),f'(\beta)\right]$.

As Christophe Leuridan noted, from [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) it follows that there is $c\in\left[\min(\alpha,\beta),\max(\alpha,\beta)\right]\subset[1,4]$ s.t $f'(c)=\frac{1}{6}\left(
f'(1)+
2f'(2)+
3f'(3)
\right)\\$.